# ¿Se puede borrar un elemento de una bbdd en Android Studio que tenga dos condiciones?

Tags: android-studio, base-de-datos, android-sqlite

estoy haciendo un gestor de series para Android, y para ello me he creado una base de datos que contiene una tabla que tiene la información de una serie (Título, capítulos, temporadas, fecha de inicio emisión...) y además, tiene 3 columnas llamadas "Vista", "Pendiente" y "Siguiendo" que tendrá un 1 o un 0 en función del estado de la serie. Ahora me surge la duda, imaginad que tengo una serie en "Siguiendo" (por lo tanto en la columna Siguiendo habrá un 1, y en las otras dos columnas tendrá un 0), y ahora la quiero poner en "Vista".

Lo que no quiero es modificar el registro que ya tengo, sino añadir la nueva serie con el atributo adecuado y eliminar la anterior. Entonces lo que yo he hecho es la siguiente función que viene en la documentación oficial de desarrolladores android:

```
public void eliminarSerie(){
    SQLiteDatabase base = basedatos.getWritableDatabase();
    String selection = BD1.NOMBRE + "=?";
    String[] selectionArgs = { Title.getText().toString() };
    int deletedRows = base.delete(BD1.Nombre_BD, selection, selectionArgs);
    Log.d("prueba", "Registros eliminados: " + deletedRows);
}
```

Pero eso me elimina todos los registros que contengan el nombre de la serie. Es decir, en mi caso, que ya tenía la serie en "Siguiendo", y luego en "Vista" porque la he añadido después, se eliminan ambos registros.

Por eso me gustaría saber si es posible añadir alguna condición más en el String selection para incluir algo tipo BD1.Siguiendo + "=?" y en String[] selectionArgs = {1}.  Es decir, quiero que borre el registro que tenga el nombre de la serie y que además tenga un 1 en la columna de Sigiuendo.

Muchas gracias a todos. Un saludo

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por qué no lo quieres actualizar?

Comment: Para ir manejando el tema de añadir y eliminar en bbdd